# Match mathematical expression with regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I am unfortunately pretty unfamiliar to regular expressions.
At the moment I try to replace some mathematical functions of the form `a**b` with `pow(a, b)`. Here is an example:

```
import re 
s = "8*pi**3*sin(x3)*sin(pi*z)**2" 
r = "[^*]\w*[*][*]\d"
```

This approach leads to:

```
In [64]: re.findall(r, s)
Out[64]: ['pi**3', ')**2']
```

So in the second case the `*`  inside the sin function is the end of the match, but it should be `'sin(pi*z)**2'`. I am not sure how to ignore the `*` inside the brackets.
Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: This is not easy to do with standard regular expressions, since matching outer brackets requires some Recursion.  Effectively, you have to parse the input equation, and then do substitutions on that parse tree.  You could do this by doing a regexp that matches inner pairs of brackets, and wrap that in some recursive function that assembles the parts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just found the sympy ccode parser, which should be best suited for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using regex this can be solved by using the sympy ccode function for example:

```
from sympy.printing import ccode
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

s = "8*pi**3*sin(x3)*sin(pi*z)**2" 
exp = parse_expr(s)

In [55]: ccode(exp) 
Out[55]: '8*pow(M_PI, 3)*sin(x3)*pow(sin(M_PI*z), 2)'
```